# Google push notification. How to validate sender and make sure that was Google?

Tags: java, google-api, verification, google-api-java-client, google-client

I have implemented in my app integration with Google by OAuth2. I can  subscribe clients on [push notification](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) (**PN**) changes in google calendar scope. PN are handled on REST controllers level. The current issue is **I can't be sure that PN was sent by Google**.

From rest request I can get sender IP, may be some more information about sender (I do not know yet which I need). Right now I think I need to have Googles` IPs range (where from PN were sent). This range I could register in my system and make sender verification than. But this idea has some disadvantages (describing all details I hope to receive answer or suggestion for alternative, better solution).

### How I can verify that PN sender was Google?

answers to next questions would help me implement one of my verification ideas:

1. Can I have Googles' IP range to use as filter (where from I can get the Googles' IP range which could be used to send PN?)?
2. Has Google special security API to check using some request information if the request were sent from Google?

---

My application details:

- maven web java project;
- spring boot based;
- REST API;
- java google client;

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  ```

Comment: You might want what to look at public key certificates. This should be what you need, sadly I don't know enough about this to write a full answer.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate

Comment: @SleepingPanda it seems really good idea, add it to answer please. I'll vote it. But I'll mark question is answered if I will know how to reach final result.

Comment: Sadly I can't really answer this question without spending multiple hours on actually learning how to do this in a safe way, as I have close to 0 experience in either java or networking. As I don't want to give a potentially harmful answer  I would just recommend to create a self answer in case this works.